# Login Authentication in YAF.net 1.9.4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, yetanotherforum, yaf

How do I use the Log in Authentication of YAF (Yet Another Forum) 1.9.4 in my current project?

The reason why I am asking is that I made yaf forum as my subfolder in my project and I still have 3 other folders other than that named Students, Teacher and Administrator.  All I want to achieve is to validate my users using the yaf login having the:

> Student role = Student Folder Access
>   and Yaf forum Registered role only
>
> Admin role = Admin Folder Access and
>   yaf forum Admin role only
>
> Teacher role = Teacher Folder Access
>   and yaf forum Moderator only

I hope someone could help me achieve this kind of thing. Any advice and suggestion will be highly sought.

Comment: thnx for the edit.. sorry i'm just new here.. pardon for my noob act ^^,

Answer (score 1):

Yet Another Forum.NET uses standard ASP.NET Membership defined in the web.config. In YAF Admin roles, link your Student, Admin and teacher roles. Then go into those roles and set the permissions to match the desired access for those roles.

Comment: thanks for the response Jaben as well as for your time... i've tried to scan and analyze the web.config file but i can't seem to find out the YAF Admin roles you are referring.. sorry for being to slow..by the way i'm currently using the v191-upgrade-web.config inside the webconfigs folder of YAF version 1.9.4.

I know, you are a busy men.. but i wish you could somehow show me a little steps on how to accomplish this.. i really wanted to use the YAF as my forum.. and learn from it.. Another thing also..i just raised a same question in yaf forum here's the link.. thank you and God Bless

Comment: http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/yaf_postst9531_Forum-Login-integration-issue.aspx

Comment: Please clarify: do you have three different forums or just 3 different roles?